# Echo only form inputs that has value

Tags: php

I have a form that has almost 32 text fields for an inverter size calculation. How do I echo only the users input and leave out the blank input.

Comment: explain more. you can put your code in your question

Comment: Answer: by checking which values have been set when the form is posted. There is a function called `isset()` in php.

Comment: be nice or don't comment,   If you have the answer, you can add this as a proper answer with an explanation, code example and link to documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if they are set or not and echo if they are

```
if(isset($_POST['your_field'])){
    echo $_POST['your_field']
}
```